# Adding the sum of a field in Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

This question has been asked before but as an absolute beginner with JavaScript I don't know how to apply this to my code. I would like the sum for both the 'G' field and sum for the 'AB' field to be displayed in the footer of my table.

Here's my code

```
<div align="center">
    <table id = 'battingtbl' class="display compact nowrap">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>YEAR</th>
                <th>AGE</th>
                <th>G</th>
                <th>AB</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for stat in playerdata.masterbatting_set.all %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ stat.year }}</td>
                <td>{{ stat.age }}</td>
                <td>{{ stat.g }}</td>
                <td>{{ stat.ab }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#battingtbl').DataTable({
        "searching": true,
        "pageLength": 40,
        "scrollX": true,
        "paging": false,
        "info": false,
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: Okay I'll work on it a little. If i can't get it ill contact you. Thanks for your help so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally do not suggest to populate DataTable with HTML source, I find this way tedious and slow.

However, assuming you want those totals to get recalculated upon each re-draw (table filtering), I'd suggest to employ [`drawCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) option to populate your totals:

```
drawCallback: () => {
             // grab DataTables insurance into the variable
              const table = $('#battingtbl').DataTable();
             // extract all the data for all visible columns
              const tableData = table.rows({search:'applied'}).data().toArray();
             // summarize row data for columns 3,4 (indexes 2, 3)
              const totals = tableData.reduce((total, rowData) => {
                total[0] += parseFloat(rowData[2]);
                total[1] += parseFloat(rowData[3]);
                return total;
              // starting point for reduce() totals for 2 columns equal to zero each
              }, [0,0]);
              // populate footer cells for columns 3, 4 (indexes 2, 3) with corresponding array total
              $(table.column(2).footer()).text(totals[0]);
              $(table.column(3).footer()).text(totals[1]);
            }
```

Above requires you to append `<tfoot>` section to the static HTML part you prepare server-side:

```
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Totals:</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
```

So, complete example might look something, like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   <div align="center">
    <table id = 'battingtbl' class="display compact nowrap">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>YEAR</th>
       <th>AGE</th>
       <th>G</th>
       <th>AB</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>2016</td>
       <td>24</td>
       <td>15</td>
       <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>2018</td>
       <td>32</td>
       <td>5</td>
       <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>2016</td>
       <td>28</td>
       <td>14</td>
       <td>9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>2015</td>
       <td>25</td>
       <td>9</td>
       <td>7</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
     <tfoot>
      <tr>
       <th colspan="2">Totals:</th>
       <th></th>
       <th></th>
      </tr>
     </tfoot>
    </table>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#battingtbl').DataTable({
       "searching": true,
       "pageLength": 40,
       "scrollX": true,
       "paging": false,
       "info": false,
       drawCallback: () => {
        const table = $('#battingtbl').DataTable();
        const tableData = table.rows({
          search: 'applied'
         }).data().toArray();
        const totals = tableData.reduce((total, rowData) => {
          total[0] += parseFloat(rowData[2]);
          total[1] += parseFloat(rowData[3]);
          return total;
         }, [0, 0]);
        $(table.column(2).footer()).text(totals[0]);
        $(table.column(3).footer()).text(totals[1]);
       }
      })
     });    
    </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your help (and that is useful) but I don't think this will work with my for loop that I'm using to pull the data. If I'm wrong on this someone please correct me. It just didn't seem to work for me

Comment: Sorry it took a while for me to respond. Yes, thank you it did work! I see youre using indexing. If my table had more columns...how would I also take the total a 5th column?

Comment: I have commented my code, so that it's easier for you to scale it.

Comment: Okay awesome! I have it fully functional now. Last thing. What about it I wanted to take the average of a column?

Comment: Come on, that's easy - divide total by the number of rows in `tableData`, e.g. `$(table.column(2).footer()).text(totals[0]/tableData.length)`